# How to fill a device with zeros, without overwriting the bytes that are already zeros?

Tags: security, dd

I have a USB flash drive usb 3, the reading speed is much more than the writing speed. 
Let's say that 99% of the flash memory is already full with zeros, and I would like to fill it with zeros until 100%, by overwriting all the memory flash with zeros `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/FLASH`.

This process is going to be long, and it will minimize the life expectancy of the flash drive.

I thought, maybe it would be much quicker to check which areas are non-zero, and overwrite only those non-zertos areas with zeros?

Are there anyways of doing this? If it is interesting, I would need all this for security reasons.

Comment: Does the device have a file system on it?  And files?  Mainly, though, if this is a one-time affair, then `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/FLASH` would be a heck of a lot faster than writing a program to read the drive one block at a time, comparing it to zeros, and rewriting it if it is.

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/FLASH` is not secure enough for legal/compliance purposes, if that is a concern readmoar on secure erase.

Comment: who do you need to be secure from?  what sort of budget does the attacker have? writing zeros to a flash drive may only hide the data.

Comment: @RonJohn
imagine that there is no file system. I want to be 100% that there are only zeros on the flash drive, regardless of whether there is a file system there or not.

Comment: @Jasen
filling the flash drive with zeros I consider sufficient in my circumstances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Security reasons aside, let's do it. We can (ab)use GNU `ddrescue`.

To detect sectors of zeros `--generate-mode` is useful.

> When `ddrescue` is invoked with the `--generate-mode` option it operates in "generate mode", which is different from the default "rescue mode". That is, if you use the `--generate-mode` option, `ddrescue` does not rescue anything. It only tries to generate a `mapfile` for later use.
>
> […]
>
> `ddrescue` can in some cases generate an approximate `mapfile`, from `infile` and the (partial) copy in `outfile`, that is almost as good as an exact `mapfile`. It makes this by simply assuming that sectors containing all zeros were not rescued.
>
> […]
>
> ```
> ddrescue --generate-mode infile outfile mapfile
> ```

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Generate-mode))</sup>

Let's pretend your device is `outfile` from previous `ddrescue` run. We cannot use it as `infile` (because `ddrescue` refuses to work when `infile` and `outfile` are the same file), we need a dummy one, `/dev/zero` will do. We should know the physical sector size of your device and use it with `-b` option. This command may help:

```
lsblk -o NAME,PHY-SEC /dev/FLASH
```

Here I assume it's `512`.

```
ddrescue -b 512 --generate-mode /dev/zero /dev/FLASH flash.map
```

Now `flash.map` describes every sector either as non-tried (`?`) or as finished (`+`), depending on whether it was full of zeros or not. The next step is to fill non-zero sectors with zeros; `--fill-mode` is perfect for this job:

> When `ddrescue` is invoked with the `--fill-mode` option it operates in "fill mode", which is different from the default "rescue mode". That is, if you use the `--fill-mode` option, `ddrescue` does not rescue anything. It only fills with data read from `infile` the blocks of `outfile` whose status character from `mapfile` coincides with one of the type characters specified as argument to the `--fill-mode` option.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Fill-mode))</sup>

We must use the same `-b` value as with `--generate-mode`, additionally `--force` to overwrite the output device. This is the command:

```
ddrescue -b 512 --force --fill-mode=+ /dev/zero /dev/FLASH flash.map
```

This time `/dev/zero` is not just a dummy argument, it's the actual source of data (zeros) written to the device.

Now `/dev/FLASH` is filled with zeros. Note there may be buffers you need to flush before you physically disconnect the device (useful links: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501437/108618), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672347/108618), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495670/108618)).

Comment: While it's slightly off this particular topic, it's worth noting that an interesting use for ddrescue's fill-mode in the context of data recovery is to fill blocks defined as bad sectors (`fill-mode=-`) with zeros after making a copy of files from the image, then make another copy of the files and do a binary comparison of the two sets of files.  Any files that don't match had at least some portion in a bad sector (and this will be partially corrupt).