# Are direct writes to block devices buffered? How do I ensure it's written to disk before removing it?

Tags: storage, cache, dd, block-device, buffer

Say I do something like `dd if=file of=/dev/sdc` (simplified for illustration), is this buffered? Can I `sync` it like I would any other filesystem write, or do I need to do something else to make sure the write is persistent?

Comment: I usually do the `sync`, and I think that is enough.

Comment: Plan ahead and [use `conv=fsync`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501437/108618) if your `dd` supports it.