# Does loopback-device-backed-LVM operations such as lvextend need call sync afterward?

Tags: lvm, synchronization, loop-device

- There is an os image file say `test.dd`, and an LVM managed partition inside.
- Enlarge the os image file size, then enlarge the partition size to full.
- Create a loopback device for `test.dd`, then get the LVM managed partition device, such as `/dev/loop0p1`
- Activate the LVM VG(Volume Group), get an LV(Logical Volume) in it, such as `/dev/dm-1`
- Enlarge PV(Physical Volume) size by `pvresize /dev/loop0p1`
- Enlarge LV(Logical Volume) size by `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/dm-1`

My questions are (actually just one: how can I safely copy the `test.dd` out to somewhere else):

1. can I copy `test.dd` out safely? (I don't care whether `test.dd` in the disk has been physically flushed out, I just want to copy it out to somewhere else, either from disk or file buffer).
2. or should I call `sync` before copy?
3. or should I detach the loopback device before copy?
4. what if failed to detach the loopback device anyway?

EDIT: I am reluctant to call `sync` command because it sometimes it  is very slow and become uninterruptible(i.e., kill -9 does not work then).

EDIT: The reason I ask the question is that I have experienced issues of data inconsistency related to loopback device and the backing file in other cases.

EDIT: For now, I use a script which call `vgchange --activate n --select vg_uuid=$LVM_VG_UUID` to deactivate the Volume Group, then `losetup --detach /dev/loop0`, followed by an `udevadm settle` then I started to copy the `test.dd` out. I just wonder whether I can copy the test.dd out without such hassle.

EDIT: sorry for wrong input for the order of command. It actually is `vgchange --activate n --select vg_uuid=$LVM_VG_UUID` -> `udevadm settle` -> `losetup --detach /dev/loop0` -> cp test.dd ...

Comment: What do you mean by "get an LG in it"? Do you mean VG?

Comment: Sorry, typo. LG should be LV, logical volume. VG means Volume Group, both are LVM terms.

Comment: Is it LV mounted and in some I/O operations?

Comment: The LV is not mounted.

Comment: If you do not extend the filesystem located in LV, the operation of lvextend is very fast (it just replace (more or less) one value) so you can copy the loop file after lvextend command ends.

Comment: yes, it is fast, but I am not sure whether pvresize and lvextend command synchronously write changes to /dev/loop0, at least to fs buffer of /dev/loop0, I am worring about that LVM write changes to /dev/loop0 asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know.  I would *hope* it's not necessary, but I'm not sure about LVM.

I expect if you deactivate the whole LVM VG, and anything else using the loop device, it would be safe.

In Linux administration, the usual norm seems to be that a final `sync` is redundant.

`umount` flushes the cache, `fdisk` calls `fsync` for you, etc.

Additionally, Linux has an [implicit sync when the last user of a block device closes it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473854/block-device-cache-v-s-a-filesystem).  So if you've deactivated everything, you haven't really avoided running `sync /dev/loop0` :-).

Though, I definitely agree with avoiding bare `sync`, i.e. flushing all devices.

And if you're deactivating everything, perhaps you can just as easily deactivate the loop device as well.  Which could help provide assurance you haven't missed anything that's holding the loop device open, and still has unwritten data.

In case it helps make you happier, the kernel doesn't write (or read) this LVM metadata.  It's all in userspace.  And there is no LVM daemon holding writeback cache.  [lvmetad](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/metadatadaemon) is a read-cache only.

Comment: thank you. Your answer is still helpful. Never mind, this is not an obvious thing. For now, I just trust the result by following way: umount all things, losetup --detach all things. I dare not trust `sync /dev/loop0` for my case.

Comment: The reason I ask the question is that I have experienced issues of data inconsistency related to loopback device and the backing file in other cases.

Comment: Added more EDIT, see my current solution, pretty close to what you have said.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking a detail look to it. Exactly `udevadm setttle` after `losetup --detach ...` is unnecessary. I typed wrong order, actually the script is `vgchange --activate n --select vg_uuid=$LVM_VG_UUID` -> `udevadm settle` -> `losetup --detach /dev/loop0`, I remember that `udevadm settle` matters after any partition related device changes, otherwise I got "device busy" error sometimes.